# How to receive String input using TextIO

Tags: java, text

I was am trying to create a simple text based randomly generated fighting game, and have create the game logic(ish). Now i would like to receive input using TextIO. I know how to receive one char, boolean, int and double. I have tried to use this (missing all other game logic), but it doesn't work

```
String input = null;

input = TextIO.getlnString();

    if (input == "help"){

    System.out.println("You are currently in "+ sTerrain + " terrain.\nAre you fighting: " + sFighting
        + "\nAre you alive: " + sLife + "\nAre there any NPC's: " + sNpc
        + "\nWhich type of NPCs: " + npc + "\nYour health is: " + currHealth + "/" + health);

        }   // Closes off help
```

If anyone has some expertise with TextIO, and could help me with allowing multiple outputs for different inputs, using the same String, it would be apprecaited

-Jordan

Comment: possible duplicate [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use String `equals` method for string comparison instead of `==`. String equals method check whether the content of two string are same whereas == checks whether two references are pointing to the same memory location or not. Change this:

```
if (input == "help"){
```

to

```
if ("help".equals(input))
```

Also note the reverse check using string literal, this helps to avoid `NullPointerException` in case input is `null`.

Check this related post:  [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: Sorry, about asking a duplicate question, i tried searching the forums, but as i didn't know what to search for i missed those ones. Sorry